# App not working after making a release to playtore as split apk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

i am trying to make my app update on playstore through unity, at my earlier builds my apk was less than 100mb so i could easily upload it to playstore. This time i am having apk size 184mb so i made split apk to upload. After the successful completion of rolling out. When i downloaded my app through playstore it gets stuck. At my initial research i found that to read the external .obb we have to take read permissions. I already had this in my app. I am getting no error when i see the logs. The same build as full apk is working fine but not the split apk. 
I am attaching link to my internal app for testing .
https://play.google.com/apps/internaltest/4700176736200004411

Extra information:- My app contains Google ArCore

Comment: Try Uploading the app as a AAB bundle, Split APK is a bit jankey sometimes

Comment: Thanks for replying i will try this and let you know.